# Modify/Adding element in layout from views

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, layout

I have a layout page that I applied for most of my views.

Now I'm asked to place a `website logo + link` in my homepage. The problem is the `<a> tag` must be placed in a `div` tag (the left menu) in my `layout` view.

If I place the link in my `layout` view, the link will appear in most of my pages, but I only need it to be appeared only in my homepage

Now the question is how do I add/modify the layout `div` tag to insert the link+logo from my home page view (Home/Index.cshtml) ?

Comment: Make use of [sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor). In the layout, `@RenderSection("sidebar", required: false)` and in the view, `@section sidebar { some content }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this :

```
public HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     ViewBag.HomeLink = "http://some.com"
  }
}
```

then in the `Layout` check if `ViewBag.HomeLink` exists and just render the anchor. That way only the home page will get the link rendered.

Comment: Thanks! Nice approach, althought I'll stick to Stephen's